# windows 8.1 autoscale by dpi on multiple screens (portrait and landscape) doing the opposite

Tags: scale, dpi, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, autosize

I'll get to the point - I have two screens:

- **32"** TV - **Landscape** mode (regular) - **res: 1920x1080**
- **20"** monitor - **portrait** mode (rotated 90 degrees) - **res: 1650x1050**

Note that in this formation the height of both screens is about the same (~4cm);

In case you've never heard of it - **windows 8.1 now tries to scale windows** so they will keep their objective size no matter what kind of size you have, by some calculation of the DPI.

Now my problem is that in my case - **it's doing the exact opposite** of what it should:

Windows 8.1 **making the windows larger on the 32"** screen - so the phenomena is just escalating.

**Any idea how to solve it**? or maybe **another program** that could manage to fix it?

- I know how to cancel this option - but it would be really cool if it will work

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: duplicate of this superuser question: http://superuser.com/questions/629376/how-to-use-different-scaling-for-every-monitor

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here!
This seems to solve it:
http://www.howtogeek.com/175664/how-to-make-the-windows-desktop-work-well-on-high-dpi-displays-and-fix-blurry-fonts/

In short: Right-click on desktop background, select "screen resolution"
Click the little blue link "make the text and other items larger or smaller"
Check box "let me choose one scaling level for all my displays"
Now you can also choose to have "smaller" scaling, which, for some reason is 100%, apply for all screens.

Hope this was helpful.